# How to join results of query with same values in a single Widget in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dictionary

I'm getting from local database( sqflite) a query using inner join, that looks like this:

```
[
{title: First Title, subtitle: First Subtitle, content_title: A_Content Title, text: First text, color: null, warning: 0}, 
{title: First Title, subtitle: First Subtitle, content_title: B_Content Title, text: Second Text, color: null, warning: 0}, 
{title: First Title, subtitle: Second Subtitle, content_title: A_Content Title, text: Third text, color: yellow, warning: 0}, 
{title: First Title, subtitle: Second Subtitle, content_title: B_Content, text: Fourth text, color: null, warning: 0}
]
```

I need a way to transform this so I can have a List of Widgets that I can use with this kind of model.

```
class Category {
  String? subtitle;
  List<Content> content;

Category({
  required this.subtitle,
  required this.content
  });
}

class Content {
  String? title;
  String? text;
  String? color;
  Int? warning;

Content({
  required this.title,
  required this.text,
  required this.color,
  required this.warning
  })
}
```

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can see to do this is using a `Map` as a third party to link contents with subtitles:

```
List yourDataList = [...];
Map _map = {};

for(int index = 0; index < yourDataList.length; index++) {

 final currentElement = yourDataList[index];

 final currentContent = Content(
      title: currentElement["title"], 
      text: currentElement["text"], 
      color: currentElement["color"], 
      warning: currentElement["warning"],
 );

 // if the subtitle will be used the first time, it will not be registered in the Map, so we initialize it with an empty list, for the next iterations with the same subtitle, this line will just be ignored.
_map[current[subtitle]] ??= [];

// now we can push elements to that List
_map[current[subtitle]]!.add(currentContent);    
}


// for getting now categories that match your model
List<Category> categories = _map.entries.map((entry) => Category(subtitle: entry.key, content: entry.value),
 ),
);
```

you can copy this code and use it in your function, you should next be able to use `catgeories` as a `List<Category>`.

Comment: I guess with _map[current[subtitle]] you meant map[currentElement[subtitle]]. But if I try to print the ending of this function I have: 
{null: [Instance of 'Content', Instance of 'Content', Instance of 'Content', Instance of 'Content', Instance of 'Content', Instance of 'Content', Instance of 'Content', Instance of 'Content', Instance of 'Content', Instance of 'Content']}ic

Comment: yes, it was a typing mistake, it is `currentElement` instead of `current`

Comment: well, seeing a `List` of `Instance of 'Content'` means that the expected result is what is actually got from the code, if you need to see the whole object when `print`ing it, you will need to override the `toString()` method of the `Content` class, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73129538/instance-of-class-name-instead-of-data-dart-flutter)

Comment: For the `null` that I'm seeing in the `Map`'s key, it means that simply a `Map` in your data has value of `null` in its `subtitle` key, which will be applied in the result as well, for this I recommend setting a breakpoint in the `for` loop and start debugging to see where/which element return null in its `subtitle` key, and make an action based on your needs, by either ignoring it or setting an alternative for it.

Comment: About the null I'm 100% sure that it doesnt have it, cause I debug it and it's not null. And also if I try to use the List you made "A value of type 'Iterable<Category>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Category>'". And If I assign an iterable it become a mess :| . I'm so stucked